# linux + what are the messages bad tty under /var/log/messages file

Tags: linux, tty, socket

under **/var/log/messages** I see the following messages "bad tty"

what the meaning of these messages?

second is it caused because some application that called - owstd ? as we can see from the log?

```
 Jan 18 01:40:09 Managnment.server login: FATAL: bad tty
 Jan 18 01:48:01 Managnment.server login: FATAL: bad tty
 Jan 18 01:58:01 Managnment.server login: FATAL: bad tty
 Jan 18 02:00:09 Managnment.server login: FATAL: bad tty
 Jan 18 02:08:05 Managnment.server login: FATAL: bad tty
 Jan 18 02:10:09 Managnment.server login: FATAL: bad tty
 Jan 18 02:18:02 Managnment.server login: FATAL: bad tty
 Jan 18 02:20:10 Managnment.server login: FATAL: bad tty
 Jan 18 02:21:02 Managnment.server logger: Failed to connect to owstd      (/var/run/FddApp/socket.owst), errno = 111

 [root@Managnment.server /]# ls -ltr /var/run/FddApp/socket.owst
 srwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Jan 15 06:03 /var/run/FddApp/socket.owst
```

Comment: You could attempt to run `ps -ef | grep Management.server` and post the output - that may (or may not) identify the process outputting these. Out of interest - what is this host doing?

Comment: Also asked on another StackExchange: http://superuser.com/questions/866203/